# Different numbering style in title and reference for sections

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, numbering, section-titles

I would like to put the number of my section in a colored box in the title but when I use a reference, I only want the number of the section to be printed and not the colored box...

I used

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\colorbox{blue}{\arabic{section}.}}
```

and it works for the title but it also put the colored box in the main text when I cite the section with `\ref{sec}`. Is there a solution to change the numbering of the section independently in the title and the reference?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) on this site you should always post a small but full self contained example that others can copy and test. Then we know your setup (document class, packages etc). (3) As you have noticed it is a very bad idea to put formatting into `\thesection`. Instead you should change how `\section` is formatted. But without any information about your doc, we cannot help you with that as there are several approaches depending on document class and packages used.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: in many cases what you want to achieve _can_ be accomplished using the `titlesec` package. If you are just doing this from scratch over one of the standard classes (article, book, etc) I would suggest this approach.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of formatting can be done using the `titlesec` package. It provides a `\titleformat` command which allows to format the title of sections or other parts of a document, and without affecting the counter reference commands (like `\thesection`). See the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for more details.

For the colored boxes around section numbers, the following example should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\colorbox{blue}{\thesection.}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\label{sec1}

Test paragraph.

\section{Second section}

Test paragraph with reference to section \ref{sec1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example updates the way the sectional unit number is printed as part of the title, introducing a special formatting mechanism. If no (new) special format is specified (on a per sectional unit basis), it defaults to `\csname the#1\endcsname\quad`, which is the default under the regular document classes anyway.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\thesectioncntformat}{\colorbox{blue}{\thesection.}\quad}
%\newcommand{\thesubsectioncntformat}{\colorbox{red}{\thesubsection.}\quad}
%\newcommand{\thesubsubsectioncntformat}{\colorbox{green}{\thesubsubsection.}\quad}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname the#1cntformat\endcsname
    \csname the#1cntformat\endcsname % Special sectional unit number formatting
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad % Default if no special format exists
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\bigskip

See Section~\ref{sec:section}, Subsection~\ref{sec:subsection} or Subsubsection~\ref{sec:subsubsection}.

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}

\end{document}
```