# How to access geometry length?

Tags: margins, geometry

Is there a keyword to access each of the lengths of the geometry package? I know `\textwidth` and `\pagewidth` but is there a way to access the left (interior) margin? Of course, this size depends if we are on an even or odd page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, I would suggest to revisit your [first question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519080/73317) and [accept](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) one of the good answers that have been given to you.

Regarding this question, LaTeX offers `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin`, but you need to add one inch to each of these lengths in order to get the margin from paper border. This is because for TeX, the document origin is located 1 inch below the top and 1 inch right of the left paper border. The example below shows how to do this computation and even print the result in centimeters with `siunitx`.

Now, remains the problem: for the current page, is it the `\oddsidemargin` or the `\evensidemargin` that applies? This is not quite straightforward, because naively checking whether the `page` counter is odd or even is not reliable. For instance, TeX could be working on page 1 when you test the counter, but if this happens to be in the middle of a long enough paragraph, some of its lines could eventually land on page 2 or even further, and this will only be known after the whole paragraph has been read—since TeX optimizes paragraphs globally.

The canonical way to deal with such issues is to work with *labels*. A label being a *whatsit* produced by the `\write` TeX primitive, it is attached to a page in the same way as a character box, and one can reliably get this page number (after at least two compilations). The `ifoddpage` package uses this technique and makes it easy to check if the place where `\checkoddpage` is used (this command writes a label) is on an odd or an even page. This is demonstrated in the `\myMarginCheck` macro below. Don't forget to compile twice because of the labels.

Apart from the left and right margins precisely addressed here, other layout parameters are more straightforward to use and can be found in the documentation of the `geometry` package. The most important ones are `\paperwidth`, `\paperheight`, `\headheight`, `\headsep`, `\topskip`, `\footskip`, `\marginparsep` and `\marginparwidth`.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
% Use a small paper size and small margins for the example
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=4cm, inner=1.7cm, outer=3.2cm,
            top=2cm, headheight=1cm, headsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage[round-mode=places, round-precision=2]{siunitx} % only for demo code

\makeatletter
% Macro for nicely printing a length in centimeters. You don't need it to *use*
% the lengths.
\newcommand*{\convertToCm}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\tmp{\strip@pt\dimexpr(#1)/7227*254\relax}%
    \SI{\tmp}{\centi\meter}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\myLeftMargin}
\newlength{\myRightMargin}

% To be called just after \checkoddpage
\newcommand*{\myComputeMargins}{%
  \setlength{\myLeftMargin}{%
    \dimexpr 1in + \ifoddpage\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi \relax}%
  \setlength{\myRightMargin}{%
    \dimexpr \paperwidth - \textwidth - \myLeftMargin \relax}%
}

\newcommand*{\myMarginCheck}{%
  \checkoddpage\myComputeMargins
  This is an \ifoddpage odd\else even\fi\ page. The left margin is thus an
  \ifoddpage inner\else outer\fi\ one and its width is
  \the\myLeftMargin, that is \convertToCm{\myLeftMargin}. The right margin is
  \the\myRightMargin, that is \convertToCm{\myRightMargin}.\par
}

\begin{document}

\myMarginCheck
\newpage
\myMarginCheck

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, thank you very much !!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I added `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` to the list of important lengths defined by LaTeX (the former was already in the code but not in the text).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a keyword to access each of the lengths of the geometry package?

```
texdoc geometry
```

Also `texdoc layouts` with help to understand lenghts of document layouts.

> but is there a way to access the left (interior) margin?

I guess that "access" mean set the margin width, that is rather simple:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```